# Remove prefix letter from column variables

Tags: r, dplyr

I have all column names that start with '`m`'. Example: `mIncome, mAge`. I want to remove the `prefix`. So far, I have tried the following:

```
df %>% 
rename_all(~stringr::str_replace_all(.,"m",""))
```

This removes all the column names that has the letter '`m`'. I just need it removed from from the start. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We need to specify the location.  The `^` matches the start of the string (or here the column name).  So, if we use `^m`, it will only match 'm' at the beginning or start of the string and not elsewhere.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
      rename_all(~stringr::str_replace(.,"^m",""))
#   ba Mbgeg gmba cfor
#1  1     2    4    6
#2  2     3    5    7
#3  3     4    6    8
```

Also, if the case should be ignored, wrap with `regex` and specify `ignore_case = TRUE`

```
df %>%
    rename_all(~ stringr::str_replace(., regex("^m", ignore_case = TRUE), ""))
#  ba bgeg gmba cfor
#1  1    2    4    6
#2  2    3    5    7
#3  3    4    6    8
```

Another option is word boundary (`\\bm`), but this could match the beginning of words where there are multi word column names

NOTE: `str_replace_all` is used when we want to replace multiple occurrence of the `pattern`.  Here, we just need to replace the first instance and for that `str_replace` is enough.

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(mba = 1:3, Mbgeg = 2:4, gmba = 4:6, cfor = 6:8)
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. I thought replace_all was if you wanted to replace all the column names. Thanks for clarifying this. I see that rename_all already does this.

Comment: @AmoghJoshi `rename_all` implies => rename all the columns. `str_replace_all` => replace every instance of the pattern in the string with replacement value

Answer (score 16):

You can use `sub` in base R to remove "m" from the beginning of the column names.

```
names(df) <- sub('^m', '', names(df))
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because it is simple and does not rely on large packages.

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can try

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(mma = 1:2, mbapbe = 1:2)
df2 <- df %>% 
  rename_at(vars(c("mma", "mbapbe")) ,function(x) gsub("^m", "", x))
#   ma bapbe
# 1  1     1
# 2  2     2
```