# Remove column name pattern in multiple dataframes in R

Tags: r, function, apply

I have >100 dataframes loaded into R with column name prefixes in some but not all columns that I would like to remove. In the below example with 3 dataframes, I would like to remove the pattern *x__* in the 3 dataframes but keep all the dataframe names and everything else the same. How could this be done?

```
df1 <- data.frame(`x__a` = rep(3, 5), `x__b` = seq(1, 5, 1), `x__c` = letters[1:5])
df2 <- data.frame(`d` = rep(5, 5), `x__e` = seq(2, 6, 1), `f` = letters[6:10])
df3 <- data.frame(`x__g` = rep(5, 5), `x__h` = seq(2, 6, 1), `i` = letters[6:10])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove prefix letter from column variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63459369/remove-prefix-letter-from-column-variables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the data frames in a list and use an anonymous function with `gsub`.

```
lst <- mget(ls(pattern='^df\\d$'))

lapply(lst, \(x) setNames(x, gsub('x__', '', names(x))))
# $df1
#   a b c
# 1 3 1 a
# 2 3 2 b
# 3 3 3 c
# 4 3 4 d
# 5 3 5 e
# 
# $df2
#   d e f
# 1 5 2 f
# 2 5 3 g
# 3 5 4 h
# 4 5 5 i
# 5 5 6 j
# 
# $df3
#   g h i
# 1 5 2 f
# 2 5 3 g
# 3 5 4 h
# 4 5 5 i
# 5 5 6 j
```

If you have no use of the list, move the changed dfs back into `.GlobalEnv` using `list2env`, but I don't recommend it, since it overwrites.

```
lapply(lst, \(x) setNames(x, gsub('x__', '', names(x)))) |> list2env(.GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: How do I do if dataframes have different names (i.e. not all starts with df)?

Comment: @PontusHedberg See comment in my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75426727/6574038).

Comment: This did not work with the error message:
Error in list2env(lapply(files_list, function(x) setNames(x, gsub("^__",  : 
  names(x) must be a character vector of the same length as x

Comment: @PontusHedberg `lst` should be a _named_ list, so `list2env` can know what the name of the df is. Obviously you `list`ed manually, try `lst <- list(df1=df1, df2=df2, df3=df3)`, then the code should work.